# Understanding Broadcom setup and kernel files

Tags: linux, kernel, wifi, broadcom, modprobe

I often install Linux distros form live usb/CDs. For that I would like to be able to setup my wireless without any internet connexion. I have a Broadcom chipset :

```
$ lspci -k
04:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n
```

I downloaded the `bcmwl-kernel-source` package as well as its dependencies (`dkms`). I am able to install those offline and make my wifi work. However I would like to understand how it works under the hood.

There is a list of `.ko` files in the modules folder:

```
$ ls /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/net/wireless/
cfg80211.ko             lib80211_crypt_tkip.ko  lib80211.ko
lib80211_crypt_ccmp.ko  lib80211_crypt_wep.ko
```

I backed them up and deleted them

```
$ rm /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/net/wireless/*.ko
$ reboot
```

After the reboot, the wifi does not work anymore. It seems those `.ko` files are important files to make the `wl` work.

I try reloading `wl` but it is not recognized anymore :

```
$ modprobe wl
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:180 kmod_module_parse_depline() ctx=0x7f9f5375d010 path=/lib/modules/3.13.0-35-generic/kernel/net/wireless/lib80211.ko error=No such file or directory
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:180 kmod_module_parse_depline() ctx=0x7f9f5375d010 path=/lib/modules/3.13.0-35-generic/kernel/net/wireless/lib80211.ko error=No such file or directory
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
```

I tried these commands to make sure the `.ko` files have something to do with the `wl` module :

```
$ apt-get autoremove bcmwl-kernel-source 
$ modprobe wl
modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found.
```

Seems normal, I reinstalled `bcmwl-kernel-source` :

```
$ sudo dpkg -i bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package bcmwl-kernel-source.
(Reading database ... 396932 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2) ...
Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.141+bdcom DKMS files...
Building only for 3.13.0-35-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 3.13.0-35-generic
Done.

wl:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/3.13.0-35-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod........

DKMS: install completed.
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu4.2) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-35-generic
```

Installing the `bcmwl` package automatically tries to insert `wl` via `modprobe`. However it fails like it did fail when I tried manually :

```
$ modprobe wl
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
```

If I restore the `.ko` files I previously removed from `/lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/net/wireless/`  and then re-install `bcmwl-kernel-source`, the script automatically inserts `wl` ( `modprobe wl` ) and my wifi card works again.

My questions are :

1) How does all this work, how are the wireless `.ko` files generated ?

2) If I boot from an Ubuntu live usb, those `.ko` files are already generated. What would I do if I am in a situation those files aren't here? Are they inter-linux-distro compatible so I can back them up?